# Using AWS Lambda, how to check if a file exists in FSx, and if it exists, move the folder it is in to a target directory in another FSx share?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-fsx

I am comfortable with Python but have no experiences with AWS, FSx, or Lambda.

I need to access an FSx share, and iterate to the nth level of every root folder.  After the nth iteration, I need to check if "example.txt" exists in that folder.  If it does, I need to move the current folder I am in to a different FSx share.

There are very few resources that I've been able to find for how to complete this task, so anything would be greatly appreciated. I would like to complete this task using Python.  Thank you.

Comment: Boto3 is a python library for working with AWS I would start with that: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/fsx.html
Try to solve the problem on your own and ask a more specific question with some sample code, to have better chance of getting an answer.